# Why is symmetric lightweight crypto only about block ciphers and not about stream ciphers?

Tags: stream-cipher, lightweight

Why is symmetric lightweight cryptography only about block ciphers and not about stream ciphers?
AFAIK stream cipher implementations cost at least three times less than block cipher ones?

Comment: When making these kind of statements, please include a reference to the place where the statements were made. We need context to explain (or in this case counter) any arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is symmetric lightweight cryptography only about block ciphers and not
> about stream ciphers?

Why that assumption? There is a lot of work concerning stream ciphers for lightweight cryptography (LWC). You can find a relevant list [here](https://www.cryptolux.org/index.php/Lightweight_Stream_Ciphers).

Plus, last week the ChaCha20-Poly1305 cipher suites (which are considered as lightweight) have been standardized in [this RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7905).

Comment: yoob, please hit the V mark on the left of the answer to accept an answer if you think answers your question.